# Sendkeys() in IE11 does not type whole text

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-iedriver

I have entered a peculiar position with my selenium where I am trying to write a whole text using .SendKeys() in IE 11.

```
  public void FillEmailAddressField()
        => _driver.FindElement(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.EmailAddressField)
                .SendKeys("Test@email.co.uk");
```

What I have noticed is that when I run the test, it sometimes misses letters during the typing at various stages. Does anyone know about this and what is a work around to get around this issue because this issue does not occur on chrome which is another browser I'm testing on.

Edit: I'm unsure but this is where I put it:

```
public class PaymentDetailsResponsive
{
    private readonly IWebDriver _driver;
    private readonly CharacterGenerator _characterGenerator;
    private readonly InternetExplorerDriver driver;

    public PaymentDetailsResponsive(IWebDriver driver)
    {
        _driver = driver;
        _characterGenerator = new CharacterGenerator();

        var internetExplorerOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions
        {
            RequireWindowFocus = true,
            EnablePersistentHover = true,
            EnableNativeEvents = true,
            IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
            IgnoreZoomLevel = true
        };
        this.driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(internetExplorerOptions);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be because of several issues. You need to provide Internet Explorer options to the webdriver. Also make sure that zoom level is 100%.
Can you add the below code. I am successfully able to automate in IE11 with the below settings.

```
  var internetExplorerOptions = new InternetExplorerOptions
                {
                    RequireWindowFocus = true,
                    EnablePersistentHover = true,
                    EnableNativeEvents = true,
                    IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true,
                    IgnoreZoomLevel = true
                };
                this.driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(internetExplorerOptions);
```

Comment: Can I ask where to put this code please. Do I just need to set a new public void method and put it in there?

Comment: You should pass this internetExplorerOptions variable into driver constructor

Comment: Your method accept driver parameter. Your should put this code where this variable is instantiated.

Comment: where are you instantiating the webdriver? Where are you calling PaymentDetailsResponsive() method?

Comment: my colleague says we cannot use the above answer due to the way our driver is set up

Comment: okay can you update the question with how your web driver code is set up. I will  change the answer accordingly.

Also did you execute the test again with Internet explorer zoom level 100%.

Comment: Yes I did Bendrem, I hve to get my colleague to come back to you as he was the one who set up the framework

Answer (score 0):

I observed similar problem with ChromeDriver. It types so fast that it misses some letters (I don't know how). So I introduced Type method in order to deal with that problem.

```
/// <summary>
/// Tyoe text into field
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">Field</param>
/// <param name="text">Text to tyoe</param>
/// <param name="speed">Speed of typing (chars per minute). 0 means default selenium speed</param>
public static void Type(this IWebElement input, string text, int speed = 0)
{
    if (speed == 0)
    {
        input.SendKeys(text);
    }
    else
    {
        var delay = (1000*60)/speed;
        foreach (var charToType in text)
        {
            input.SendKeys(charToType.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(delay);
        }
    }
}
```

I use it instead of SendKeys()

```
public void FillEmailAddressField()
       => _driver.FindElement(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.EmailAddressField)
               .Type("Test@email.co.uk", 150);
```

You have to adjust speed of typing. Accroding to the wikpedia the record looks as follow:

```
The fastest typing speed on an alphanumeric keyboard, 216 words in one minute, was achieved by Stella Pajunas in 1946 on an IBM electric.[5][6][7] As of 2005, writer Barbara Blackburn was the fastest alphanumerical English language typist in the world, according to The Guinness Book of World Records. Using the Dvorak Simplified Keyboard, she maintained 150 wpm for 50 minutes, and 170 wpm for shorter periods. Her top speed was 212 wpm. Current online records of sprint speeds on short text selections are 290 wpm, achieved by Guilherme Sandrini on typingzone.com and 295 wpm achieved by Kathy Chiang on TypeRacer.com. For longer passages, Sean Wrona holds the record with 174 wpm on a 50-minute test taken on hi-games.net.[8]
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to provide a loop for each character and also updated my IEDriver from a 32bit to a 64bit due to my computer being a 64bit.

Example:

```
        var towncity = _driver.FindElement(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.AddressTownCityField);
        var towncitytext = "LEEDS";

        foreach (char c in towncitytext)
        {
            towncity.SendKeys(c.ToString());
        }
```